# Ajustar texto de variable editandolo desde la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este código:
Para editar la ruta donde se guarda la imagen desde la base de datos:

```html
<?php
  $host = 'localhost'; 
  $user = 'root'; 
  $pass = ''; 
  $db = 'img'; 
  //creo mi conexion a la base de datos 
  $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db); 

//capturamos los datos del fichero subido    
$type=$_FILES['img_up']['type'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['img_up']["tmp_name"];
$name = $_FILES['img_up']["name"];
$consulta = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM datos") or die($mysqli->error);

//Creamos una nueva ruta (nuevo path)
//Así guardaremos nuestra imagen en la carpeta "images"
$nuevo_path = $consulta.$name;
//Movemos el archivo desde su ubicación temporal hacia la nueva ruta
# $tmp_name: la ruta temporal del fichero
# $nuevo_path: la nueva ruta que creamos
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$nuevo_path);
//Extraer la extensión del archivo. P.e: jpg
# Con explode() segmentamos la cadena de acuerdo al separador que definamos. En este caso punto (.)
$array=explode('.',$nuevo_path);
# Capturamos el último elemento del array anterior que vendría a ser la extensión
$ext= end($array);
//Imprimimos un texto de subida exitosa.
echo "<h3>La imagen se subio correctamente</h3>";
// Los posible valores que puedes obtener de la imagen son:
echo "<b>Info de la imagen subida:</b>";
echo "<br> Nombre: ".$_FILES['img_up']["name"];      //nombre del archivo
echo "<br> Tipo: ".$_FILES['img_up']["type"];      //tipo
echo "<br> Nombre Temporal: ".$_FILES['img_up']["tmp_name"];  //nombre del archivo de la imagen temporal
echo "<br> Tamanio: ".$_FILES['img_up']["size"]." bytes";      //tamaño
?>
```

Pero en la linea de: `$nuevo_path = $consulta.$name;`

Me da error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\subir\subir.php on line 17

Supuestamente lo de `$consulta` es donde esta la ruta que quiero editar desde la base.

Comment: Puedes mostrar el error que te bota por favor?

Comment: `Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\subir\subir.php on line 17`

Comment: La linea 17 es `$nuevo_path = $consulta.$name;
`

Comment: Como? En $consulta estaría la ruta de la imagen

Comment: Recuerda por favor usar el boton [edit] y agregar la informacion a la pregunta

Comment: y si $consulta tiene la ruta, que tendria $consulta.$name (que como te dijeron no es una sintaxis valida)

Comment: $consulta es la consulta a la tabla, que tiene la ruta de la imagen, y $name, como dice el nombre, y el código, es el nombre de la imagen que tiene al momento de surbirla, y editar que? Si estoy aclarando algo. No tiene nada que ver.

Comment: El error, deberia estar en la pregunta. escribiste la pregunta, pero no pusiste el error.

Comment: Quiero decir que hagas un `var_dump($consulta);` para ver que te esta trayendo toda tu consulta y agrega esa info a la pregunta editandola como sugirio gabianchi

Comment: Hay un error de comprensión en tu código, pero también un error de lógica. Como han dicho los compañeros, `query` devuelve un objeto al cual hay que aplicarle alguno de los métodos `fetch` para obtener el dato de la columna que quieras. Pero no entiendo por qué ni para qué seleccionas todas las filas y columnas de la tabla `datos` ¿? ¿quieres usar todas las filas/columnas de esa tabla para algo? o ¿quieres una fila en específico?

Comment: Hola, sí, pasa que en esta tabla solo hay dos culumnas, `id | carpeta1` que solo tiene un id 0 y la ruta en carpeta1, por ejemplo "img/"

Comment: Aunque ahora sea una sola fila la tabla puede crecer, por lo que conviene que siempre uses un filtro en tu consulta. De todos modos, la instrucción puede ser: `SELECT carpeta1 FROM datos`  y para obtener el valor de la carpeta aplicas uno de los métodos `fetch` al resultado, por ejemplo este: `$datos = $consulta->fetch_assoc();`  y luego, buscas el valor de la columna `carpeta1` dentro del array asociativo que obtuviste anteriormente: `$nuevo_path = $datos["carpeta1"].$name;`

Answer (score 2):

Esto sucede porque el resultado de la consulta:

> SELECT * FROM datos

No devuelve un string que se puede concatenar con $consulta.

Intenta con:

```
$consulta = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM datos") or die($mysqli->error);
$resultado = $consulta->fetch_row();
$nuevo_path = $resultado['elatributodelselect*'].$name;
```

Lo anterior funciona, solo sí sabes con certeza que el resultado que necesitas se encuentra en el primer resultado de la consulta.
De lo contrario deberás hacer una consulta mas restrictiva a e iterar.
Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, pero que iría en "elatributodelselect", el resultado esta en el id 0, osea la primer columna de la base, a eso te referis?

Comment: Iría la columna de la cual necesitas información, es decir el SELECT * FROM datos devuelve todas las columnas que tiene la tabla datos. Sí la columna es path por ejemplo iría $resultado['path']. Saludos.

Comment: Ahi probé y me sale esto: `Notice: Undefined index: SELECT * FROM datos in C:\xampp\htdocs\subir\subir.php on line 17`

Comment: Que raro, la línea 17 esta idéntica a la cual tenías anteriormente.

Comment: Puse esto: `$nuevo_path = $resultado['SELECT * FROM datos'].$name;
`

Comment: No, en el 'atributodelselect' iría el nombre de la columna, por dar un ejemplo podría ir 'id'.

Comment: Me queda `Undefined index: datos`

Comment: datos es una tabla o un campo de la tabla? te esta diciendo que ahi va el nombre del campo de la tabla de la cual queres obtener el valor

Comment: Es la manera de concatenar variables en PHP, puede parecer un poco raro, pero el . funciona como +.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tener en cuenta que [**mysqli->query**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) te devolverá un objeto del tipo [**mysqli_result**](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php) que,

> Representa el conjunto de resultados obtenidos a partir de una consulta en la base de datos.

Para obtener un dato de ese conjunto de resultados puedes usar distintos métodos listados [**aquí**](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php), según sea tu caso.

Por ejemplo puedes usar [**fetch_all**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) cuando tienes varias filas como resultado devuelto:

```
$name = $_FILES['img_up']["name"]; 

$consulta = $mysqli ->query("SELECT * FROM datos") or die($mysqli->error);

$filas = $consulta->fetch_all($consulta);

// asumiendo que lo que deseas está en tu primera fila
$nuevo_path = $filas[0]->ruta.$name;
```

En el caso de que solo sea una fila puedes usar [**fetch_array**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

```
$name = $_FILES['img_up']["name"]; 

$consulta = $mysqli ->query("SELECT * FROM datos") or die($mysqli->error);

$fila = $consulta->fetch_array($consulta);

$nuevo_path = $fila['ruta'].$name;
```